# Two dimensional array of objects in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to make array in as3 like this :

```
countdowns[bodyID][powerupName] = { time: powerup.getTime(), onRemove: onRemove };
```

I have been trying for hours but no luck..
Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question with a little more detail about what your powerups and bodies do? It sounds like you might just want an `Array` of `Dictionary` objects, but how you fill that depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but you have to declare each object separately and you have to call index number instead of variable name

Say I have an array of colors with a sub array of types of that color filled with objects describing RGB

```
var colors:Array = [];
var red:Array = [];
var darkRed:Object = { r : 256, g : 100, b : 100 }
red.push( darkRed ); //darkRed is now part of red
colors.push( red ); //red is now part of colors
```

To access `darkRed`, you would do this:

```
colors[0][0]; //that is darkRed
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish :

```
var countdowns:Array = new Array;
countdowns[bodyID] = new Array;
countdowns[bodyID][powerupName] = { time: powerup.getTime(), onRemove: onRemove };
```

The second dimension of the countdowns Array is achieved by inserting an array into each element of the first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

While this certainly can be done, but it's possible you're overcomplicating things. Perhaps a single-dimensional Array ob tailored Objects will suit better.

```
var ob:Object=new Object();
ob.bodyId=bodyId;
ob.powerup=powerup; // direct link to powerup might serve you better!
ob.onRemove=onRemove;
countdowns.push(ob);
```